# CAS without forcing authentication

Tags: java, spring-mvc, authentication, single-sign-on, cas

With regards to using CAS for SSO, the main way of performing this is, upon a user visiting a site backed by CAS, that app redirects the user's browser to CAS's login page for authentication. At this point, one of two things happens a.) If the user is already "logged into" CAS, CAS redirects the user back to the other app, otherwise b.) the user is forced to log into CAS.

My question is, is there a way for the app to get the authentication from CAS if it exists for the user, but not force login if it does not exist? Essentially providing service a. without service b.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the Chairman of CAS and founder of CAS in the cloud (https://www.casinthecloud.com).

I think you are looking for the `gateway` feature: using this extra parameter when calling the /cas/login url won't display the login page if the user is not authenticated.